How to limit fetched object size in git2 in rust
I'm writing a program to do things with git. I need to have a way of limiting the size of cloned objects. I know you can do this using git clone through the cli using some kind of git clone --filter={some rules etc} but I can't seem to work out how to do this using git2 for rust.
Here is some example code to approximate how I'm cloning things:
let mut callbacks = RemoteCallbacks::new();

let mut fo = git2::FetchOptions::new();
fo.remote_callbacks(callbacks);

let mut builder = git2::build::RepoBuilder::new();
builder.fetch_options(fo);

let repo = builder.clone(some_url, some_path).unwrap();

I have a suspicion that it has something to do with adding a custom header into the fetch options but the docs aren't clear enough for me to understand how to do this. The docs in question.
The functionality I'm trying to create is only pulling objects from a remote under some size using some kind of fetch filter like this one. Something like --filter=blob:limit=1024.
I hope this question is clear enough.
Cheers.

You can set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 before running the git clone command that you know limits the size of the cloned objects, to see how are the headers set. This only works for clones over http.

@jthulhu is this just an env var? This sounds very helpful, will be looking into it.

@jthulhu When I do this with github it automatically redirects to https:// and I don't see any new information (except for the fact is splits the output into two packfile sets.) and I don't see anyway of preventing this? What kind of headers should I be expecting here?

git2-rs is just a thin layer over libgit2, and given https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/5564 I think libgit2 simply does not support this feature.
